# Including a href in a picture source media element

Tags: html

I'm using the following code to show an image in my website:

```
  <div id="wideheader">
     <div id="header">
        <div id="headerimage">
            <picture>
              <source
                media="(max-width: 900px)"
                srcset="images/eye1.jpg">
              <img
                src="images/eye2.jpg"
                alt="">
            </picture>
           <div id="headerteaser">
              Beautiful Eyes
           </div>
        </div>
     </div>
  </div>
```

How could I include an href so that a click on the image would take the visitor to another page?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrapping element in `a` tag will do the trick.

```html
<a href="https://www.google.com/">
  <picture>
          <source
            media="(max-width: 900px)"
            srcset="images/eye1.jpg">
          <img
            src="images/eye2.jpg"
            alt="">
  </picture>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to enclose the html in anchor tags `<a>` where you need a clickable link

```html
<div id="wideheader">
  <div id="header">
    <a id="headerimage" href="#"> 
        <picture>
          <source
            media="(max-width: 900px)"
            srcset="images/eye1.jpg">
          <img
            src="images/eye2.jpg"
            alt="">
        </picture>
       <div id="headerteaser">
          Beautiful Eyes
       </div>
    </a>
 </div>
</div>
```

---

edit:
Incase you need the href to be only on the image, Enclose the required html snippet in the anchor tags with the required href, And it should work as expected

Answer (score 0):

```
  <div id="wideheader">
     <div id="header">
        <div id="headerimage">
            <picture>
              <source
                media="(max-width: 900px)"
                srcset="images/eye1.jpg">
              <a href=""><img
                src="images/eye2.jpg"
                alt=""></a>
            </picture>
           <div id="headerteaser">
              Beautiful Eyes
           </div>
        </div>
     </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Element `a` is not allowed as child of `picture` element. You should wrap `picture` in `a` element.